# Adding PushNotification service to an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement Push Notification from server site in my application since many day but I am unable to get push notification service in my application. but I am getting this error:

> error : Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 'no valid' aps- environment' entitlement string found for application UserInfor=0x170140 {NSLOcalizedDescription=no valid 'aps- environment' entitlement string found for application}

Can any one help me out to resolve this error?

Or give me some more clear steps what I am missing in my application.

Actually I have to Send notification on some changes in my Server side application. Like If some one post a Blog on the site it should be shown in every app holder. For this we need to generate the JSON. So my main worry is how to connect my Server or my JSON updates with PushNotification service. I Think now it's more clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help you:
http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

and try to do a bit of googling!!

Comment: How to set JSON data or JOSON data comes from which server. I ready follow this but I didn't get solution.

Comment: Could you please more specific on this!!

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620).

Comment: Actually I have to Send notification on some changes in my Server side application. Like If some one post a Blog on the site it should be shown in every app holder. For this we need to generate the JSON. So my main worry is how to connect my Server or my JSON updates with PushNotification service. I Think now it's more clear.